# How to re-post an old post?

Tags: posts

I am in need of re-posting random posts to the front page of the blog to make them fresh. Is there any hook that could help me achieve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the Old Post Promoter plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/old-post-promoter/

This plugin promotes old posts by sending them back onto the front page and into the RSS feed. It does it randomly choosing an eligible post and updating the publication timestamp. The post then appears to be the latest post on your WordPress blog. "You down with OPP? Yeah you know me!"

Answer (score 0):

You can [sticky](http://en.blog.wordpress.com/2008/09/08/sticky-posts/) the post, which will place that at the top of your blog list.

Comment: That would do it for just one post right? I am looking for some plugin that would automatically post the article again.

Answer (score 0):

Use featured post option. that can show multiple posts at the same time.

Comment: Do you mean sticky posts?

Comment: yeah, they are sticky posts. you can show multiple posts using carousels etc. check this tutorial http://pixel2pixeldesign.com/how-to-create-wordpress-featured-posts-nivo-slider/